# Remove numbers from string square bracket

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a huge string which contains a lot of numbers in square brackets. For instance:

[1] this is an example
...
[123] another example

How can I remove the numbers and the brackets from my text string?

My current code to extract the text from a file:

```
text = txtFile.read()
text = str(text)
text = text.replace("\\n", " ")
text = " ".join(text.split())
```

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you give a sample input and an expected output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `re.sub`:

```
import re

text = txtFile.read()
text = str(text)
text = re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', '', text)
```

The regex pattern `\[\d+\]` should match any bracket term which has one or more numbers in it.

Note that `re.sub` by default will do a replacement against the entire input string.